# Ignoring img tags in height styling

Tags: css

I want to control the height of a div so it's always at least 8rem tall and then grows as text wraps onto new lines. This text will be overlayed on an image that's pulled in with an img tag, so setting the height to grow based on the content will take into account the img tag as well as the text.

If I was using using background-image instead of inline img tags, this would be pretty easy to solve, but img tags are better for accessibility and have more functional support in static website systems like Gatsby.

So, I'm trying to set the height in such a way that takes into account the text only, and doesn't consider the child img tag.

I'm not a CSS master, so I'm wondering if there's a way to do that that I'm not considering.

Here's a codepen with more context: https://hod.ge/css-hgt

Comment: Hi John. Please paste your code here (even if link would be working). FYI Your link is not working.

Comment: Could you explain a bit more what you want to happen with the image. Is it to be contained in the eventual div, or to cover it or to have width 100% or ....

Answer (score 0):

You can use min-height property to that div.
Ex:

```
div{
  min-height: 8rem; 
}
```

Ref: [1] https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_dim_min-height.asp
More content you add the div height increases.

I exactly didn't get the image part. I will get back to you if I find any leads...

Answer (score 0):

The idea of an overlay is a 'relative' positioned container with an image and a 'absolute' positioned text. The image is a responsive image so the image will maintain the correct aspect ratio on smaller screens. The text will be positioned somewhere in the container, use the top & left & width settings to adjust it for your layout.

After giving the overlay container the correct size, the image and text will respond to that size. As you asked for, the min-height is 8rem.

An example:

```css
body {
    font: 400 1rem/1.1 "Segoe UI", Arial, sans-serif;
}
.overlay {
    position: relative;
    width: 120px;
    min-height: 8rem;
    background-color: #eee;
    font-size: 0.75rem;
}
.overlay-img {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    border: 0;
}
.overlay-text {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0.5rem;
    left: 10%;
    width: 80%;
    text-align: center;
    color: grey;
}
.overlay p {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="overlay">
    <img class="overlay-img" src="https://picsum.photos/id/206/300/200">
    <div class="overlay-text">Some text</div>
    <p>The description of this photo.</p>
</div>
```